# How to display PHP errors in browser? I am working on Linux with Firefox browser

Tags: php

I am having trouble with this piece of code below. Whenever I run this file from browser it shows me the empty. But I want to display error in browser

```
<?php
echo "hello satya"
?>
```

Comment: what coddddddeeeeee??

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Search your issue before posting. You will then often be able to find an answer faster and SO won't contain as many duplicates.

Comment: Code looks like it should display empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try Adding This on top of your php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file,Change this

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
```

Or, In PHP Code,Add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```